# ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy'] from Pandas Created Conda Environment

Tags: pandas, numpy, anaconda, conda

I created a new conda environment as follows

```
conda create -n NAME python=3.5
```

Added edit, of course activate the environment like so

```
activate NAME
```

Installed these libraries all at once

```
conda install numpy scipy pandas scikit-learn jupyter matplotlib
```

relevant libary versions that conda installed

[image: lib versions]

when importing pandas ge

> ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Can anyone replicate this installation of env on windows?  I am thinking one of the files version are causing this and cannot find a solution, barring an externality.
Have uninstalled and installed pandas, numpy, etc all libraries, have also tried installing with pip even, nothing is working.  Have even created another environment from scratch same error is occurring.

Comment: Did you activate the environment before installing?

Comment: yes, will edit question and include that, very familiar with conda environments forgot to include

Answer (score 0):

Conda should have installed a number of libraries when you build python 3.5 in the new environment. If you run "conda list" in the command line of the newly built environment it will show the packages you have by default. Try to build the environment with "conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda" so it uses the anaconda python and will auto install packages.

Comment: irrelevant as that merely installs a predefined set of packages, the installation environment and explicit packages are a standard method to build a light environment